# Keras + tensorflow gives the error "no attribute 'control_flow_ops'"

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run keras for the first time.  I installed the modules with:

```
pip install keras --user
pip install tensorflow --user
```

and then tried to run https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py.

However it gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'control_flow_ops'
```

These are the versions I am using.

```
print tensorflow.__version__
0.11.0rc0
print keras.__version__
1.1.0
```

> What can I do to get keras to run with tensorflow?

Comment: use tensorflow 0.10 instead

Comment: @vgoklani 0.10 is not available through  pip it seems. How can I install it,

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation

Comment: @vgoklani Thank you, that worked.

Comment: This isn’t actually a solution, just a work-around. I’m unfortunately having the same problem with tensorflow 0.11 :(

Comment: Same problem with `tensorflow 0.12.1` and `keras 1.0.5`, but works with `keras 1.2.1` and `tensorflow 0.12.1`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is an issue between Keras and TF, Probably tf.python.control_flow_ops does not exist or not visible anymore.
 using below import statements you can resolve this issue

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.python.control_flow_ops = tf
```

For Details check:
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3857

Comment: I have the same problem. when tried your solution, I got: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'

Comment: tf has changed a lot in last 1 or 2 year. I don't think this solution is relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem when it turns out `keras` was using the `Theano` backend. To fix it do one of these:

- In `~/.keras/keras.json` set `"backend": "tensorflow"`.
- Set the environment variable `KERAS_BACKEND` to `tensorflow`.

See [Keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/) documentation for more information.

Comment: @Ilan What do you mean? If you get this error when you just want to use Theano, that probably means that you don't have it installed. That was certainly true for me when I got this error: I didn't have Theano installed because I hadn't planned to use it! If you want to use Theano sometimes and TensorFlow other times, use the `KERAS_BACKEND` environment variable I said in my answer; note that environment variables can be different in different processes. If you want to use both in one program, you might be out of luck. In any case, you probably need to post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

If not Using TensorFlow 1.0.0; use tf.python_io in later versions

```
import tensorflow as tf 

tf.python_io.control_flow_ops = tf
```