# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'merge_all_summaries'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda

Ubuntu 14.04.

Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

I installed Tensorflow follow the tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/

when I enter

> ~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist

and attempt to run the already existed python file:

> fully_connected_feed.py

I met the below **AttributeError**:

```
:~/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist$ python fully_connected_feed.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Extracting Mnist_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting Mnist_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting Mnist_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting Mnist_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 229, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/hok/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 225, in main
    run_training()
  File "fully_connected_feed.py", line 154, in run_training
    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'merge_all_summaries'
```

But the same code run successfully in other computer. So I think that must be the configuration problem in my computer.

I have followed the same steps to install tensorflow many times and use it to run Deep Learning for a period of time. But it was the first time I met such problem.

There are many suggestions in Google say such kind of AttributeError maybe the problem with *python version*. But it's not.

Comment: Are the tensorflow versions the same on both machines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: 'module' object has no attribute 'scalar\_summary'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066244/tensorflow-module-object-has-no-attribute-scalar-summary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solven this problem with the help of teammates.

It's the **tensorflow versions** problem.

Tensorflow version in the former computer is **0.12.1**. Tensorflow version in the computer met AttributeError is **1.0.0**. This new tensorflow version has change some **Python api**, So the AttributeError met.

---

In this computer which met AttributeError:

```
:~$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
>>> __tf.version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__tf' is not defined
>>> tf.__version__
'1.0.0'
>>>
```

In the former computer:

```
:~$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import tensorflow as tf
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
>>> tf.__version__
'0.12.1'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/40066895/4533188 you can read up on an answer to a similar problem: The answer is to migrate as appropriate. Check out https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration. There you see that

```
- tf.merge_summary
    - should be renamed to tf.summary.merge
- tf.train.SummaryWriter
    - should be renamed to tf.summary.FileWriter
```

(Actually SummaryWriter has also been changed.) So you should be able to solve your problem if you write before your code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.merge_all_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all
tf.train.SummaryWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter
```

(I had the same issue in [Keras + TensorFlow: “module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'merge_all_summaries''”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42585620/4533188).)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update depreicated  Tensorflow API in the python files you are running i.e. fully_connected_feed.py

Look for tf.merge_all_summaries() and replace it with tf.summary.merge_all()

Present version of Tensorflow uses

```
tf.summary.merge_all()
```

instead of the old version which used

```
tf.merge_all_summaries()
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.merge_all_summaries = tf.compat.v1.summary.merge_all
tf.train.SummaryWriter = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter
```