# Keras + TensorFlow: “module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'merge_all_summaries''”

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Very similar to [Keras + tensorflow gives the error "no attribute 'control_flow_ops'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046619/keras-tensorflow-gives-the-error-no-attribute-control-flow-ops), from the Convolutional autoencoder example from https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html I get the error

```
[...]lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py in _set_model(self, model)
    478                     tf.histogram_summary('{}_out'.format(layer),
    479                                          layer.output)
--> 480         self.merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    481         if self.write_graph:
    482             if parse_version(tf.__version__) >= parse_version('0.8.0'):

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'merge_all_summaries'
```

I tried

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.merge_all_summaries = tf
```

but that did not work. What should I do?

In [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'merge_all_summaries'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481938/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-merge-all-summaries) the error is mentioned. I also have the version 1.0.0. But what is the solution? I don't want to downgrade TensorFlow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make42 is absolutely correct that the changes they describe in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585785/3574081) must be made in order to migrate a codebase to work with TensorFlow 1.0. However, the errors you are seeing are in the Keras library itself. Fortunately, these errors have been fixed in the Keras codebase [since January 2017](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/aa18604fec4a309658bcc83b6aa595b5f0838d36), so upgrading to [Keras 1.2.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Keras/1.2.2) or later will fix the error for you.

Comment: Can we do this with anaconda or at least `pip`?

Comment: I think `pip install -U keras` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to migrate as appropriate. Check out https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration. There you see that

```
- tf.merge_summary
    - should be renamed to tf.summary.merge
- tf.train.SummaryWriter
    - should be renamed to tf.summary.FileWriter
```

(Actually SummaryWriter has also been changed.) So instead of

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.merge_all_summaries = tf
```

you should write

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.merge_all_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all
tf.train.SummaryWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter
```